# sharepoint email workflow not sending mails

Tags: sharepoint-designer

i am not able to initiate mails from one of my workflow . i have created one workflow with 2 stages, first one detects the recurrence and second one creates the new task if the first task has been completed.
And another workflow which sent out mails "3" days before start date. This sending mails 3 days before start date is not working, however if i will create the workflow just to sent mails on the start date then that would work fine.[image]

Answer (score 0):

I don't see anything in these steps that would send an email 3 days before the start date.  This workflow calculates a reminder date 3 days before the start date, but then the next step only sends the email if the Start Date is before the Reminder Date -- since the Reminder date is always 3 days before Start Date, Start Date will Never be before Reminder Date, thus the email will not be send.

I think you need to add a step before the `Send Emails` step that says if Reminder Date is greater than Today, then use a `Pause until Date` to pause until the Reminder Date.  Then you can remove the second conditional in the Email step so that all you are checking is the Status before sending the email.